# Image Recognition in real time

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, image-recognition

I am searching for a way, to achieve real time image recognition in dynamically, I have to scan object (it can be a product) and show details about that object.

Is it possible by using native frameworks like `ARKit`? Or I have to go with third party libraries by using recent methodology?

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbplSdh0lGU

Can someone suggest a way?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Please check [this link first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Will you know what the products are in advance e.g coke bottle, bottle of water?

Comment: No, we can't know in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible by using Apple's native `CoreML` and `Vision` frameworks.

**But you need to know about all the products in your library in advance.**

You can read about it in this Medium post: [CoreML Machine Learning on iOS](https://medium.com/@hunter.ley.ward/machine-learning-on-ios-overview-a3642960e2af).

Also, watch this [WWDC 2017 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/506/) about Vision/CoreML frameworks.

Comment: Thanks andy, Let me try your suggestions.